# Repeatedly use view controller for online app and still have a back button

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue, back

I'm relatively new to programing in general and am currently designing a database project but now I ran into a logic problem which my head cant get straight.

The problem is that I have a view controller that loads in a list of things from the database and than when you click on it it opens a detail, from that detail there is a button that loads in a list like the previous one we came from so I use the same view controller and just request different data. So far, everything is nice and dandy.

But now comes the problem there is a back function so when I now press back once I go back to the detail and than when I press back a second time it loads the last data that I had loaded on that list so it loads the wrong data.

A good example of what I would like to have is the Facebook friend function when I click on my friends it loads a list and than I can click on their friends I see the same list with different data but when I go back two steps it loads in my friends again. I made it work with a very confusing and impractical system of registers but this is very bad because it sometimes throws errors.

So does anyone know how I could achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm unclear what you want. Using your Facebook example is illustrative. If you're looking at your friends, click on one of your friends, and then look at their friends, when you click back twice, I'd expect you to be back at your list of friends. Are you saying that this is not what you'd expect? Or are you saying that this is not what you're achieving?

Comment: Im saying that that is what I wnat to achive

Comment: When you say "repeatedly use view controller", are you reusing the same instance or creating a new instance of the same view controller? How precisely are you "reusing" this view controller?

Comment: Im using the same instance by sequeing to back to the same instance of the controller in the storry board.

Comment: I dont know if that is the best way though thats why Im hear

Comment: No, you really would probably want a separate instance each time. You can use the same view controller class and code and NIB and/or storyboard scene, but instantiate a new one each time. That way one will not affect the other (assuming you don't use global variables).

Comment: If you're still having problems, your question should include an example of how you're segueing/pushing from the details screen to the next instance of the list. We need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see a lot of code, but just the bare minimum to reproduce the sort of problem you're describing. But right now, we're left guessing how you are "reusing" this view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "reuse" this view controller, I would suggest creating a new instance of that view controller each time. This way, (assuming you avoid use of any global variables, but rather only use properties of the class) you're guaranteed that each time you create new instance of the view controller, it won't affect other instances that might exist elsewhere in the navigation controller's stack of previously instantiated view controllers.

Comment: Thanks that seems like a resonable thing to do the onley problem is how do I create a new instance and what exactly do you mean by "only use properties of the class" ?

Comment: Are statics global variables ?

Comment: How to instantiate new one each time? If doing it programmatically, you use `let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(...)`. If using segues, just have a segue from the details back to the list view controller. You'll end up with circular reference of view controllers (which you generally avoid), but in this case, it's what you want.

Comment: When I say "only use properties", I'm just suggesting that you want to avoid `static` variables, as well as "global" variables outside of the `@implementation` and `@interface` blocks. You don't want variables that persist across instances of that view controller.

Comment: OK thanks sounds good ima trye it out XD